# How to include .h file containing structure only in to static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I want to create a static library in Objective C iOS. But in that I want to define only structure in .h file. There won't be any .m file file that.

```
struct ApiResponseStruct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const A;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const B;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const C;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * const D;
};

extern const struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;
```

So, When I create my static library and including it into demo application. It is always showing me linker error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_ApiResponse", referenced from:
      -[TestLib setApiResponse] in libTestLib.a(TestLib.o)
      -[TestLib getApiResponse] in libTestLib.a(TestLib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, Could someone please help me in resolving this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: create a objective C protocol file. it will just have .h . Now your other classes should apply this protocol. Tell me if m not clear or if more info needed.



How to create protocol file:
1. New file
2. Cocoa touch -> Objective C Protocol

Comment: I am not creating any protocols. What I need to do is, to create .h file with only simple structure which I mentioned in the question. I want that file to be included in my static library and I need to use that file in my demo application.

Comment: Yeah i know that. what i am saying is, create a Obj-C protocol file, list the properties you need in your struct in the file. Don't put structure there. Now use this protocol file in your application. If any class needs particular struct, let them abide the protocol. am I able to convey my thought?

Comment: Yeah I got you. But my requirement is different. So, I need to do it like that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this forward declaration,

```
extern const struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;
```

you promise the compiler that there is a non-static *definition* of `ApiResponse` in one of your files. It appears that none of your .m files provides this definition, so the linker complains that `ApiResponse` is undefined.

Add

```
const struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;
```

to one of your .m or .c files. It could be in your library or in your application, but it needs to exist in order for your project to compile properly.

> How do I assign a value to ApiResponse.A = @"String"? I get an error when I try it.

You get an error because you are trying to assign it in a static context. You need to make the assignment at runtime, for example, from the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your application delegate:

```
// Define your struct outside the method
struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ... // Your regular "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' code...
    ApiResponse.A = @"Quick";
    ApiResponse.B = @"Brown";
    ApiResponse.C = @"Fox";
    ApiResponse.D = @"Jumos";
    return YES;
}
```

You wouldn't be able to keep this `const`, because it is not possible to provide meaningful static initialization for `NSString*` fields. You should either change the header to this

```
extern struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;
```

or use a different approach: make a pointer to `ApiResponse` a `const`, and point it statically to a non-const `struct`, like this:

```
extern const struct ApiResponseStruct *ptrApiResponse;
```

In the app delegate file:

```
struct ApiResponseStruct ApiResponse;
const struct ApiResponseStruct *ptrApiResponse = &ApiResponse;
```

Users of your API would have to write `ptrApiResponse->A` instead of `ApiResponse.A`, but the compiler will be able to enforce const-ness.

Comment: Can you help me in assigning the value to ApiResponse.A = @"String"?? Which is even giving me error

Comment: I am getting error. Redefinition of "ApiResponse" with a different type: 'struct ApiResponseStruct' vs 'const struct ApiResponseStruct'.

Comment: @user3124624 You are right, `const` would need to go, or you should use a pointer (see the edit).

Comment: Thank you for your Response. But we have some 3rd party static library and .h files exposed to us. In that they created and structure like this. We are trying to replicate the same thing and want to understand how they are doing.

Comment: Actually we want this structure to be converted to C# and accessed in MonoTouch. We did all the binding for Static library to MonoTouch but unable to replicate that structure in C# and access it.  So, could you please help me in that also.

Comment: @user3124624 I think they resorted to some kind of a hack then - for example, casting `const`-ness away before assigning `ApiResponse`.

Comment: @user3124624 I am not familiar with monotouch at all, but this would make a great question for someone who knows it. Write it up as a separate question, but explain these three points: #1 You have a third-party static library that provides the header (show them the header), #2 You need to link to that library from an application developed with monotouch (is this even possible?), and #3 you need to access `ApiResponse` from your program in C#. Ask them what kind of external definitions you need for interoperability.